# OpenCV : Video processing in background queue

Tags: ios, opencv, image-processing, video-processing, nsoperationqueue

Successfully able to detect square object from video stream using powerful `OpenCV`. Everything was fine, except video lags frame due to calculation burden on main thread.

As you can see below code snippet, I added `NSOperationQueue` inside `CvVideoCameraDelegate` delegate method `processImage:(cv::Mat&)image` When I tried to run `findSquaresInImage` on background operation queue and `UIImageFromCVMat` main queue.

```
- (void)processImage:(cv::Mat&)image

NSOperationQueue *videoProcessQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[videoProcessQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    // do some time consuming stuff in the background

    cv::Mat matResultImage = [self findSquaresInImage:image]; //---> Method will return the square object and takes more than 0.3 seconds

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        // update the UI here

        self.imageView.image = [UtilityClass UIImageFromCVMat:matResultImage]; //---> Updates the UI

    }];
}];

}
```

But I got exception in this line `cv::pyrDown()`

```
- (cv::Mat)findSquaresInImage:(cv::Mat)_image
{

   std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > squares;
    cv::Mat pyr, timg, gray0(_image.size(), CV_8U), gray;
    int thresh = 20, N = 2;
    cv::pyrDown(_image, pyr, cv::Size(_image.cols/2, _image.rows/2)); //----> HERE I GOT EXCEPTION
    cv::pyrUp(pyr, timg, _image.size());
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    //remaining logic goes here........ ...... ...... ...
}
```

[image]

What is wrong here? Any alternative way to improve ?

**//UPDATE :**

Same issue even with GCD blocks :

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        cv::Mat matResultImage = [self findSquaresInImage:image];
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

           self.imageView.image = [JKUtilityClass UIImageFromCVMat:matResultImage];
    });
});
```

Comment: No answer from this thread http://answers.opencv.org/question/30959/ios-video-processing-is-very-slow/

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to resolve after 2 major changes :

- Directly mapping image from `processImage:(cv::Mat&)image` to `CvVideoCamera` object. Never used already initialized parent view `self.imageView`.
- To speedup process, included [OpenCVSquares](https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVSquares) Detection library.